# Magento 2 : Form values save in db and grid

Tags: magento2, grid, forms

Can anyone help me to save form values & submit to grid and database ?

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Comment: i have a two custom fields in frontend after submit, need to save in db and admin section grid

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i need a frontend form submit to admin grid

Answer (score 10):

**For save record in Database :**

=> Create a **/app/code/Company/Blog/Setup/InstallSchema.php** file :

```
<?php

namespace Company\Blog\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('company_blog');
        // Check if the table already exists
        if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            // Create company_blog table
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'blog_title',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Title'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'blog_content',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Content'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'user_email',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Email'
                ) 
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_date',
                    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false],
                    'Created Date'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'status',
                    Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
                    'Status'
                )

                ->setComment('Company Blog')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

=> Create a model file **/app/code/Company/Blog/Model/Blog.php** :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Blog\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Blog extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('Company\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Blog');
    }
}
```

=> Create a resource model file **/app/code/Company/Blog/Model/ResourceModel/Blog.php** :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Blog\Model\ResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
class Blog extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('company_blog', 'id');
    }
}
```

=> Create a collection file **/app/code/Company/Blog/Model/ResourceModel/Blog/Collection.php** :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Blog;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Company\Blog\Model\Blog', 'Company\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Blog');
    }
}
```

=> Create **/app/code/Company/Blog/Controller/Index/Save.php** Controller :

```
<?php
namespace Company\Blog\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Company\Blog\Model\BlogFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class Save extends Action
{

    protected $_modelBlogFactory;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_sessionManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        BlogFactory $modelBlogFactory,
        PageFactory  $resultPageFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_modelBlogFactory = $modelBlogFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        $resultRedirect     = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $BlogModel          = $this->_modelBlogFactory->create();
        $data               = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
        $date               = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa'); 

        $BlogModel->setData('blog_title', $data['blog_title']);
        $BlogModel->setData('blog_content', $data['blog_content']);
        $BlogModel->setData('user_email', $data['user_email']);
        $BlogModel->setData('created_date', $date);
        $BlogModel->setData('status', $data['status']);

        $BlogModel->save();

        $this->_redirect('blog/index');
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The data has been saved.'));
    }
}
```

**=> Follow the steps to display data in grid :**

> /app/code/Company/Blog/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Company_Blog::view" title="Company Blog" module="Company_Blog" sortOrder="1" resource="Company_Blog::view"/>

        <add id="Company_Blog::display" title="Blog Post" translate="title" module="Company_Blog" sortOrder="20" parent="Company_Blog::content_blog" action="blog/grid/index" resource="Company_Blog::display"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

> /app/code/Company/Blog/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="blog" frontName="blog">
            <module name="Company_Blog" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> /app/code/Company/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
class Index extends Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

    }


    public function execute()
    {

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Company_Blog::display');
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('CMS'), __('CMS'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Grid View'), __('Manage Grid View'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Manage  Blog'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> /app/code/Company/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/Grid.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

class Grid extends  \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Queue list Ajax action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
       $this->_view->loadLayout(false);
        $this->_view->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages($this->messageManager->getMessages(true));
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> /app/code/Company/Blog/Block/Adminhtml/Grid.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Blog\Block\Adminhtml;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{

    protected $_template = 'grid/view.phtml';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        $addButtonProps = [
            'id' => 'add_new_grid',
            'label' => __('Add New'),
            'class' => 'add',           
            'button_class' => '',
            'class_name' => 'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton',
            'options' => $this->_getAddButtonOptions(),
        ];
        $this->buttonList->add('add_new', $addButtonProps);

        $this->setChild(
            'grid',
           $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\Blog\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Grid', 'grid.view.grid')
        );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }


    protected function _getAddButtonOptions()
    {

        $splitButtonOptions[] = [
            'label' => __('Add New'),
            'onclick' => "setLocation('" . $this->_getCreateUrl() . "')"
        ]; 
        return $splitButtonOptions;
    }


    protected function _getCreateUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'blog/*/new'
        );
    }


    public function getGridHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('grid');
    }
}
```

**=> For preparing columns in grid :**

> /app/code/Company/Blog/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Grid.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Blog\Block\Adminhtml\Grid;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    protected $moduleManager;

    protected $_blogFactory; 

    protected $_status;   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Company\Blog\Model\BlogFactory $blogFactory,
        \Company\Blog\Model\Status $status,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_blogFactory = $blogFactory;
        $this->_status = $status;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    } 

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('gridGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('grid_record');

    } 

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $collection = $this->_blogFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

         $this->addColumn(
            'id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'blog_title',
            [
                'header' => __('Title'),
                'index' => 'blog_title',                
                'class' => 'xxx'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'user_email',
            [
                'header' => __('User'),
                'index' => 'user_email',                
                'class' => 'xxx'
            ]

        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'status',
            [
                'header' => __('Status'),
                'index' => 'status',
                'type' => 'options',                
                'options' => $this->_status->getOptionArray()
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'created_date',
            [
                'header' => __('Created At'),
                'index' => 'created_date'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'edit',
            [
                'header' => __('Edit'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => 'blog/*/edit'
                        ],
                        'field' => 'id'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'delete',
            [
                'header' => __('Delete'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Delete'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => 'blog/*/delete'
                        ],
                        'field' => 'id'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );




        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }


    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('id');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            [
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('blog/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            ]
        );

        $statuses = $this->_status->toOptionArray();

        array_unshift($statuses, ['label' => '', 'value' => '']);
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'status',
            [
                'label' => __('Change status'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('blog/*/massStatus', ['_current' => true]),
                'additional' => [
                    'visibility' => [
                        'name' => 'status',
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'class' => 'required-entry',
                        'label' => __('Status'),
                        'values' => $statuses
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );


        return $this;
    }


    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('blog/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }


    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'blog/*/edit',
            ['id' => $row->getId()]
        );
    }
}
```

**=> For get status value in grid :**

> /app/code/Company/Blog/Model/Status.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Blog\Model;

class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;

    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;


    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }


    public static function getOptionArray()
    {
        return [self::STATUS_ENABLED => __('Enabled'), self::STATUS_DISABLED => __('Disabled')];
    }


    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }


    public function getOptionText($optionId)
    {
        $options = self::getOptionArray();

        return isset($options[$optionId]) ? $options[$optionId] : null;
    }
}
```

Last steps are files is view layout xml, here also we have to layout for index and grid

> /app/code/Company/Blog/view/adminhtml/layout/blog_grid_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="formkey"/>
    <update handle="blog_grid_block"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Blog\Block\Adminhtml\Grid" name="adminhtml.blog.grid.container"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> /app/code/Company/Blog/view/adminhtml/layout/blog_grid_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <update handle="formkey"/>
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Company\Blog\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Grid" name="admin.grid.grid"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```

> /app/code/Company/Blog/view/adminhtml/templates/grid/view.phtml

```
<?php echo $block->getGridHtml() ?>
```

clear cache and you can see grid page

Comment: Hi @Emipro tech Thanks for the answer but i need a frontend form submit to admin grid –

Comment: Your form data submit in database and fetch that record in admin grid. Right?

Comment: ok thanks i will try it and get back to you